# Hg: How can I find the files I have changed between two revisions (or dates)?

Tags: mercurial

In mercurial I am trying to find the list of files I have touched.

I came close with the commands:

```
hg log -u joe.doe@foo.com
```

which gives the changesets of joe.doe

```
hg status --rev 3870:4100
```

which gives the files that were changed between revisions.

Is there a way to know the files I have touched between two revisions or two dates?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine your two things and throw a bit bash post-processing onto the output of log:

```
hg log -r20000:tip -u joe.doe@foo.com --template "{files % '{file}'}\n" | sort | uniq
```

Without the bash-postprocessing, you'll have files listed as often as they are changed.

Comment: works like magic. Btw, for the old versions of Mercurial, it s --template instead of -T.

Comment: Great. I'll amend the answer to use the long form